# Simple html button to get data from a page and save that data in a data base at the same time

Tags: php, html

I am using `PHP_Storm` and I'm building a web site where I need to add a shopping cart option to it.

What I want is a simple button to get the `reference` of the particular classified `( reference ( $this->reference = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10)).time();)` 
is already declared in the web page and I can assign it as the vale of the button) and save that data as a string in the entity `cart`. JS or AJAX or whatever possible way. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

use *AJAX*  to do this,

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'store-data-url',
    type:'post;
    data:{
    //data-to-store
    },
    success: function(response){
    //get response 
    console.log(response);
    },
    error:function(error){
    //get error
    console.log(error);
    }
```

this is so simple hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

An simple way to you send your PHP variable from the browser to the server:

```php
<form action="..." method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="value" value="<?php echo $this->reference ?>" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And on the server you have to store the value of `$_REQUEST['value']` into your database.